# How to save job info (qstat) in SGE when submitting to qsub?

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine, qsub

When submitting a job, I am able to provide `qsub` with the path for the standard output and the standard error.

On the other side, while my job 12345 is running, I can access to extra info related to it by using `qstat -j 12345`.

My question is if there is a way to set a path in `qsub` to automatically record the same kind of information provided by `qstat` into a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of finding out what happened to a job. The name of the utility is [qacct](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qacct). Is is a by dirty but with some grep juggling you can get what you need.

For instance to get information about the exit status, jobnumer and task for the last day in the cluster, run:

```
 qacct -j -d 1 | egrep -i "exit_status|jobnumber|taskid"
```

Answer (score 0):

qstat is a server command that queries the internal data structures about the job. There are no options in qsub that would allow you to query that information.

(Atleast not the torque version of qsub which I am familiar with).

As a work around, you could query the output of qstat from within the job (Assuming your system admin has enabled client commands on the nodes).

```
/usr/bin/qstat $PBS_JOBID > $PBS_O_PATH/qstat.txt
```